# Does a function change when you multiply both the denominator and numerator by the same function?

Tags: functions

For example:

$ 1) \, f(x): 3x+3$

$2) \, f(x)= \frac{(3x^2-3)}{(x-1)}$

If you simplify the second function it becomes the first, but isn't the function, in its present form, undefined for $x = 1$?

Comment: The functions are the same where they are defined. They may have different domains of definition. For an extreme case, multiply the top and bottom by the zero function; the result is still the same wherever they are both defined, but the "zero divided by zero" version isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: I think you have already answered your own question. (I am taking the "isn't the function ... ?" remark as a rhetorical question; you know the answer is "it is.")

Comment: You could say that your second function is the first function with an annoying *removable singularity* added to it.

Answer (score 7):

we have $$\frac{3(x^2-1)}{x-1}=\frac{3(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}=3(x+1)$$ only for $$x\ne 1$$

Comment: So just to explicitly confirm, the functions are different?

Comment: the functions are different, it si $$f(1)=4$$ in the first case and $$f(1)$$ is not defined in the second case

Comment: I'm assuming this is a typo but I calculate $ f(1) = 6 $ when $ f(x) = 3(x+1) $. I agree $ f(1) $ is undefined when $ f(x) = \dfrac{3(x^2-1)}{x-1} $

Comment: yes it is $$f(1)=6$$ sorry it is corrected

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Please don't use $$\text{display math}$$ in comments unless you really need it. For most purposes, single dollar signs are more than enough.

Answer (score 3):

The only point at which the function may be changed is when the numerator and denominator equal to zero. Then you will get an undefined point as we have $0/0$. We merely take these points into account as a root is removed for each of these points

Similarly, when we divide $f(x)$ by $g(x)$ we must take into account where $g(x)$ is equal to zero, and see whether or not $f(x)$ is also zero at these points. Additionally, multiplying a function by another may add additional roots which we must account for

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a function is a *mapping* from one set to another set.
Also recall that it is fundamentally defined as a ***set*** of (input, output) pairs.

The formula for a function is merely an "algorithm"<sup>1</sup> for defining this mapping.
It is used to avoid listing an infinite number of pairs like $\{(0,3),(1,6),\ldots\}$ for the set.

Naturally, if your algorithm (formula) fails somewhere, then you haven't specified the mapping there. This is *commonly understood* to mean that your function is undefined wherever the formula you specify for it fails to produce a value.

Therefore, if you *do* intend the function to be defined there, you do need to change the formula so that it doesn't fail there. Otherwise, you have specified a different function, because the mapping—which is a set of pairs—is not the same.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I put "algorithm" in quotes since it's not quite the computer-science notion of an algorithm.</sub>